# Tie variable multiple times

Tags: perl, tie

Can I tie a variable multiple times? I'd try it myself, but I'm not sure of the syntax. I want to tie a hash to [Cache::Memcached::Tie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Cache%3a%3aMemcached%3a%3aTie) *and* [IPC::Shareable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aShareable).

Comment: Why is this a syntax problem? Couldn't you try `my $t1 = tie $something, ...; my $t2 = tie $t1, ...`? Apart from that I have no idea whether this works. Intuitively it should though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to tie two classes to single item. Running tie second time just remove original link and replace with new one.

It should be possible to write some kind of multi-dispatch, though. I mean writing a class that accept multiple other classes and call their respective methods like `FETCH` or `STORE`.

Answer (score 6):

No. Confirming bvr's guess, a variable can only have a single "tied" magic. When you call `tie` on an already-tied variable, the existing tie-magic (and the associated tied object) is discarded before the new tie is created.

Toy example:

```
package Foo;
sub TIESCALAR { return bless [] }
sub DESTROY { print "Destroying Foo\n" }

package Bar;
sub TIESCALAR { return bless [] }
sub DESTROY { print "Destroying Bar\n" }

package main;
tie my $var, "Foo";
print "Tied to ", ref tied $var, "\n";
tie $var, "Bar";
print "Tied to ", ref tied $var, "\n";
```

Output:

```
Tied to Foo
Destroying Foo
Tied to Bar
Destroying Bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Not only is this not possible, but it's not sensible either. What is a fetch supposed to mean in this context? How to deal with them returning two different values?

What I suspect you want is a multilevel caching system, you may want to look into [CHI](http://metacpan.org/module/CHI) for that.

Comment: CHI may work once I `tie` the object to allow `IPC::Shareable` to work. I'll have to give that a shot.